# Can I make this R foreach loop faster?

Tags: r, multicore, doparallel

Thanks in advance for your help.

The short of this is that I have huge foreach loops that are running much slower than I'm used to, and I'm curious as to whether I can speed them up -- it's taking hours (maybe even days).

So, I've been given two large pieces of data ( by friend's who needs help).  The first is a very large matrix (728396 rows by 276 columns) of genetic data for 276 participants (I'll call this M1).  The second is a dataset (276 rows and 34 columns) of other miscellaneous data about the participants (I'll call this DF1).  We're running a multilevel logistic regression model utilizing both sets of data.

I'm using a Windows PC with 8 virtual cores running at 4.7ghz and 36gb of ram.

Here's a portion of the code I've written/modified:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(car, svMisc, doParallel, foreach, tcltk, lme4, lmerTest, nlme)

load("M1.RDATA")
load("DF1.RDATA")

clust = makeCluster(detectCores() - 3, outfile="") 
#I have 4 physical cores, 8 virtual.  I've been using 5 because my cpu sits at about 89% like this.
registerDoParallel(clust)
getDoParWorkers() #5 cores

n = 728396
res_function = function (i){
   x = as.vector(M1[i,]) 
   #Taking one row of genetic data to be used in the regression
   fit1 = glmer(r ~ x + m + a + e + n + (1 | famid), data = DF1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
   #Running the model
   c(coef(summary(fit1))[2,1:4], coef(summary(fit1))[3:6,1], coef(summary(fit1))[3:6,4], length(fit1@optinfo[["conv"]][["lme4"]][["messages"]]))
   #Collecting data, including whether there are any convergence error messages
}

start_time = Sys.time()
model1 = foreach(i = 1:n, .packages = c("tcltk", "lme4"), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
   if(!exists("pb")) pb <- tkProgressBar("Parallel task", min=1, max=n)
   setTkprogressBar(pb, i)
   #This is some code I found here to keep track of my progress
   res_function(i)
}
end_time = Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
stopCluster(clust)
showConnections()
```

I've run nearly identical code in the past and it took me only about 13 minutes.  However, I suspect that this model is taking up more memory than usual on each core (likely due to the second level) and slowing things down.  I've read that BiocParallel, Future, or even Microsoft R Open might work better, but I haven't had much success using any of them (likely due to my own lack of know how).  I've also read a bit about the package "bigmemory" to more efficiently use the large matrix across cores, but I ran into several errors when I tried to use it (failed workers and such).   I'm also curious about the potential of using my GPU (a Titan X Pascal) for some additional umph if anyone knows more about this.

Any advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: Where is the bottleneck?

Comment: I would try ```future_apply(M1, 1L, res_function)``` modifying ```res_function``` to accept the row vector from ```M1```. That way your workers wouldn't have to worry about the *entire* ```M1``` and then immediately sunsetting it. Also, did you try it single core to see if it is slow? Sometimes multicore slows you more than it helps